# If I add a blank <script src=""></script> to my page, what would happen?

Tags: javascript

For some reasons, I have to add this line to my page:

```
<script src=""></script>
```

I would like to know, if there is no URL in the src attribute. What would happen?

I tested with my Mac + Chrome and it seems everything is fine. It's not blocking my other scripts nor sending unwanted network requests.

Comment: Nothing. It does nothing.

Comment: That said... Why? Why do you need that on the page?

Comment: For things like this - just _try it_. What's the worst that could happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There **is** a URL in the `src` attribute.

It's a relative URL that resolves to the URL of the HTML document containing the script element.

Historically, the browser would make another request for the URL of that HTML document, get an HTML document back, and then either:

- refuse to execute it (throwing an error in the developer tools) because it has a `text/html` `Content-Type` response header *or*
- try to execute it and throw an error because an HTML document is not valid JavaScript.

Some modern browsers have explicit guards against this. Firefox, for example, throws the warning *‘src’ attribute of `<script>` element is empty.*

Comment: Are you sure? I do not see such a request in the network tab

Comment: @mplungjan — It will use the cached version if your cache headers don't prevent it.

Comment: I've seen behavior like this with `img` tags. Don't recall seeing it with `script` tags, but I might never have had empty `src`s

Comment: HTML5 explicitly states that `src` must contain a valid _non-empty_ URL; so browsers implementing this correctly should not cause any request in this situation.

Comment: To further add information. The DOM representation of the blank src of `script` tag, it represented as `(unknown)` by Google Chrome. And also like Quentin said, it was also register as a formal request but as `text/html`

Comment: [Repro'd on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTCcm.png). It _does_ result in a new http call. (Feel free to use this in your answer if you wish)

Comment: @Cerbrus in that particular situation, where you append the script element via jQuery, it does. Having `<script src=""></script>` directly in the HTML from the start however _does not_. Not sure if that’s due to how exactly jQuery handles this though, and if the result would be different using native DOM methods to create and append a new script element.

Comment: @misorude You are right. If the tag is directly put in HTML the request would never be sent.

Comment: btw, @ everyone - I have to do this in my code is because I use some other code to generate HTML code. And that code can't be changed (I don't have that much jurisdiction).